# How to extend Bundle product type in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, bundle-product

When I create new product type and extend Bundle, I don`t have "Bundle Items" tab, how I can get the same functionality in my custom product type like in Bundle product? [image]

product_type.xml

`<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
<type name="super_bundle" label="Super Bundle Product" modelInstance="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type" composite='true' indexPriority="40" sortOrder="50">
    <priceModel instance="Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Price" />
    <indexerModel instance="Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\Price" />
    <stockIndexerModel instance="Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\Stock" />
    <allowedSelectionTypes>
        <type name="virtual" />
    </allowedSelectionTypes>
    <customAttributes>
        <attribute name="refundable" value="true"/>
    </customAttributes>
</type>
</config>`

When I use

[image: ----------]

Comment: i have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: Face same issue in magento 2.4 have you found any solution for the same ? Thank you :)

Comment: please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258316/extending-bundle-product-in-custom-type-ends-up-without-add-option-button thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope you were both able to Figure out your issue, If not I believe the Following should be the fix.

`<vendor>/<module>/etc/product_types.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="custom_bundle" label="Custom Bundle Product" modelInstance="<vendor>\<module>\Model\Product\Type" composite='true' indexPriority="40" sortOrder="50">
        <priceModel instance="Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Price" />
        <indexerModel instance="Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\Price" />
        <stockIndexerModel instance="Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\Stock" />
        <allowedSelectionTypes>
            <type name="simple" />
            <type name="virtual" />
        </allowedSelectionTypes>
        <customAttributes>
            <attribute name="refundable" value="true"/>
        </customAttributes>
    </type>
</config>
```

`<vendor>/<module>/Model/Product/Type.php`:

```
<?php

namespace <vendor>\<module>\Model\Product;

/**
 * Class Type
 * @package <vendor>\<module>\Model\Product
 */
class Type extends \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type {

    const TYPE_CODE = 'custom_bundle';

    // Class Intentionally left blank
}
```

`<vendor>/<module>/Setup/InstallData.php`:

```
namespace <vendor>\<module>\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use <vendor>\<module>\Model\Product\Type as CustomPoductType;

/**
 * Class InstallData
 * @package <vendor>\<module>\Setup
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $fieldList = [
            'price',
            'special_price',
            'special_from_date',
            'special_to_date',
            'minimal_price',
            'cost',
            'tier_price',
            'weight',
            'price_type',
            'sku_type',
            'weight_type',
            'price_view',
            'shipment_type',
        ];

        foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
            $applyTo = explode(',', $eavSetup->getAttribute(Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to'));

            if (!in_array(CustomPoductType::TYPE_CODE, $applyTo)) {
                $applyTo[] = CustomPoductType::TYPE_CODE;
                $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                    Product::ENTITY,
                    $field,
                    'apply_to',
                    implode(',', $applyTo)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From your question i think the main part you are missing is the EAV Attributes assignment. if you were to take a look at the `Magento_Bundle` module `Setup/InstallData.php` you will see that this has a list of existing attributes that it assigns plus creates some new ones, it is the new attributes that are required, specifically `shipment_type` for the highlighted area in the screenshot.

Comment: add option button still missing.....

Comment: Also, if enable dynamic price the price is not disabling.. Do we need edit any other files apart from these three?

Comment: Thank you @Nathan Day after add missing attribute in apply_to showing bundle item tab but still missing add  option button have you any idea for the same

Comment: @SagarDobariya this is the answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258316/extending-bundle-product-in-custom-type-ends-up-without-add-option-button